# Find and Replace first NA in each column without for loops

Tags: performance, r, for-loop, apply, na

Trying to do this without For Loop but can't figure it out.

I want to replace the first NA in a column with a default value of 0.0000001.

I am doing Last Observation Carried Forward (LOCF) imputation but want to give it a default value.

If I have the following data.frame:

```
> Col1        Col2        Col3        Col4
> 1           NA          10          99
> NA          NA          11          99
> 1           NA          12          99
> 1           NA          13          NA
```

I want it to look like this:

```
> Col1        Col2        Col3        Col4
> 1           0.0000001   10          99
> 0.0000001   NA          11          99
> 1           NA          12          99
> 1           NA          13          0.0000001
```

This is the code I haev that works but is very slow...

```
#Temporary change for missing first observation
for (u in 1:ncol(data.frame))
{
  for (v in 1:nrow(data.frame)) 
  {
    #Temporary change the first observations in a row to 0.0000001 until it encounters a value that isn't NA
    if(is.na(temp_equity_df_merge2[v,u]))
    {
        temp_equity_df_merge2[v,u]=0.0000001
    }
    else break
  }
```

I want to use apply or some variant that will be faster.  I am looping over 20 columns and 1 million rows.

Thanks ahead of time for the help.

Comment: since you mention LOCF, you may be interested in `library('zoo'); ?na.locf`

Comment: I appreciate that.  That is what I am using but if the first observation is blank, it ignores it (e.g., it wouldn't return anything for column 2).  Also, it only seems to work on each column seperately so when I was using cbind afterwards, they columns would be of different lengths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, you can use `apply` to apply a function to each column.  The function will replace the first `NA` with 0.0000001 and return a matrix.  Then you can use `na.locf` to fill-in the remaining `NA`s.  Finally, I wrapped it all in `data.frame` since you asked for a `data.frame` instead of a `matrix`

```
data.frame(na.locf(apply(dat, 2, function(x) {
    firstNA <- head(which(is.na(x)), 1) #position of first NA
    x[firstNA] <- 0.0000001
    x
})))
   Col1  Col2 Col3    Col4
1 1e+00 1e-07   10 9.9e+01
2 1e-07 1e-07   11 9.9e+01
3 1e+00 1e-07   12 9.9e+01
4 1e+00 1e-07   13 1.0e-07
```

Answer (score 4):

you can apply a function to each column:

```
myfun <- function(x) {
  x[which(is.na(x))[1]] <- 0.1

  return(x)
}

> data.frame(apply(dat, 2, myfun))
   v1  v2 v3   v4
1 1.0 0.1 10 99.0
2 0.1  NA 11 99.0
3 1.0  NA 12 99.0
4 1.0  NA 13  0.1
>
```

Answer (score 1):

Given you have such a large data set, I would use `data.table` and `set` to avoid copying the data. Both the `apply` solutions copy the data at least once.

The solution involves a for loop, but an efficient one ( doing length(valid_replace) things each of which are instantaneous)

```
library(data.table)

DT< -as.data.table(dat)

replacing <- lapply(DT, function(x)which(is.na(x))[1])

valid_replace <- Filter(Negate(is.na), replacing)

replace_with <- 0.0001

for(i in seq_along(valid_replace)){
  set(DT, i = valid_replace[i], j = names(valid_replace)[i], value = replace_with)
}
```